$0\rightarrow M'\rightarrow M\rightarrow M''\rightarrow 0$ exact, then the tensorized sequence is also exact
I want to demonstrate that if $0\rightarrow M'\rightarrow M\rightarrow M''\rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence, then the induced sequence $0\rightarrow M'\otimes_A N\rightarrow M\otimes_A N\rightarrow M''\otimes_A N\rightarrow 0$ is also exact if the first sequence splits.
I believe that proving the injectivity of the map $\alpha\otimes \text{id}_N: M'\otimes_A N\rightarrow M\otimes_A N$ is sufficient. Is this assertion correct? If so, I'm unsure about the next steps in the proof.

If you're happy with the statement that the tensor product is right exact then proving injectivity is (obviously) sufficient, yes. As for the proof, think about retracts.

Yes, it is sufficient to prove the injectivity of $\alpha \otimes id_N$.

Assume the exact sequence in the problem is
$0 \longrightarrow M' \xrightarrow[]{\alpha} M \xrightarrow[]{\beta} M'' \longrightarrow 0 $. Then the splitting condition implies there is a morphism $f : M \longrightarrow M'$ such that $f \circ \alpha = id_{M'}$.
Then $f \otimes id_N \circ \alpha \otimes id_N = id_{M' \otimes N}$. So $\alpha \otimes id_N$ is injective.

What should I do if I don't have the splitting condition but instead I know that $N$ is a finitely generated free $A$-module?

@claudia Use the fact that $M\otimes_R R^n \cong M^n$, and that $f\otimes id_{R^n}\cong f\oplus f \oplus \cdots \oplus f$ under this isomorphism.  Or you could phrase it in terms of tensoring by $R$ being the identity, and tensor products commute with direct sums.

@claudia, the further question is about "flat modules". I can tell you that any  direct summand of free modules is a flat module. Any I think these properties are included in any books about rings and modules.
